# Django formsets __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have created two models w_orders(workorders) and tobjects. I have two templates, one is only for creating a workorder and this works fine and one other template which contains data of both workorders and objects. tobjects is related to the table w_orders and I want to be able to create x number of objects for a workorder. For every workorder an object is created automatically. So far I have created the template and I can't quite figure how to display only the related objects for a certain workorder. For example for workorder no 1 I get the objects that are created for other workorders. As well I cannot add or edit an object related to the workorder. This is my code:

models.py

```
class w_orders(models.Model): 
    Id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    datedefwo = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    datesched = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    datefinished = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sign = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    statusid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    typeid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    navkonsid = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    navname = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navcustadr = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navdebt = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    navpropcode = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navdepcode = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navphoneno = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    navreasoncomp = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    nightshift = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    priority = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    mapurl = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Id




class tobjects(models.Model): 
    oid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    wid = models.ForeignKey(w_orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objtypegisid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    objgisid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condgenid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condriskid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condratsid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condmhcoverid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condmhwallid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipehydrsid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipehydreid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipedepvolsid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipedepvoleid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipedepconssid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    condpipedepconseid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
    txt = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.oid

    @receiver(post_save, sender=w_orders)
    def ensure_order_exists(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('created', False):
            tobjects.objects.get_or_create(wid=kwargs.get('instance'))
```

workorder_edit.html

```
{% extends 'workorders/base.html' %}
{% block jumbotron2 %}
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Navbar example</h1>
<p class="lead">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the top-aligned navbar works. As you scroll, this navbar remains in its original position and moves with the rest of the page.</p>
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/navbar/" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
</div>
{% endblock %}


{% load static %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {{ formset.management_form }}
            {% for form in formset %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
            {% endfor %}   
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
```

workorder_create.html

```
{% extends 'workorders/base.html' %}
{% block jumbotron2 %}
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Navbar example</h1>
<p class="lead">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the top-aligned navbar works. As you scroll, this navbar remains in its original position and moves with the rest of the page.</p>
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/navbar/" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
</div>
{% endblock %}


{% load static %}

{% block content %}


<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="page-header">
<h2> Create Workorder </h2>
</div>

{{ form.non_field_errors }}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form.datedefwo.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.datedefwo.id_for_label }}">Defined:</label>
        {{ form.datedefwo }}
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form.typeid.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.typeid.id_for_label }}">Order type:</label>
        {{ form.typeid }}
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form.datesched.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.datesched.id_for_label }}">Date Scheduled:</label>
        {{ form.datesched }}
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form.statusid.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.statusid.id_for_label }}">Status:</label>
        {{ form.statusid }}
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form.navreasoncomp.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.navreasoncomp.id_for_label }}">Request:</label>
        {{ form.navreasoncomp }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form.navcustadr.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.navcustadr.id_for_label }}">Address:</label>
        {{ form.navcustadr }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form.navname.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.navname.id_for_label }}">Customer:</label>
        {{ form.navname }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form.navphoneno.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.navphoneno.id_for_label }}">Tel No:</label>
        {{ form.navphoneno }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form.mapurl.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.mapurl.id_for_label }}">Map:</label>
        {{ form.mapurl }}
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def workorders_list(request):
    workorders_all = w_orders.objects.all().values_list('Id', flat=True)
    return render(request, "workorders_list.html")

def home_page(request):
    return render(request, "home_page.html")

def workorder_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateWorkorder(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            CreateWorkorder_item = form.save(commit=False)
            CreateWorkorder_item.save()
            return redirect('/workorder/' + str(CreateWorkorder_item.Id) + '/')
    else:
        form = CreateWorkorder()
    return render(request, 'workorders/workorder_create.html', {'form': form})




tobjectsFormSet = modelformset_factory(tobjects, fields=['wid', 'objtypegisid', 'objgisid', 'condgenid', 'condriskid', 'condratsid', 'condmhcoverid', 'condmhwallid', 'condpipehydrsid', 'condpipehydreid', 'condpipedepvolsid', 'condpipedepvoleid', 'condpipedepconssid', 'condpipedepconseid', 'txt'])

def workorder_edit(request, id=None):
    item = get_object_or_404(w_orders, Id=id)
    form = CreateWorkorder(request.POST or None, instance=item)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_order=form.save()
        new_order.save()
        formset = tobjectsFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, extra=0)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('/workorder/' + str(item.Id) + '/')
    else:
        formset = tobjectsFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    return render(request, 'workorders/workorder_edit.html', {'formset': formset, 'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class CreateWorkorder(forms.ModelForm):
    navreasoncomp = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ))
    navcustadr = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ))
    navname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ))
    navphoneno = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ))
    mapurl = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ))


    class Meta:
        model = models.w_orders
        fields = ['Id', 'datedefwo', 'datesched', 'datefinished', 'statusid', 'sign', 'typeid', 'comments', 'navid', 'navkonsid', 'navdebt', 'navpropcode', 'navdepcode', 'nightshift', 'priority', 'stid', 'datesched', 'statusid', 'navreasoncomp', 'navcustadr', 'navname', 'navphoneno', 'mapurl']
        widgets = {
            'datedefwo': DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
            'datesched': DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
            'datefinished': DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
            'navreasoncomp': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':3, 'cols':42}),
        }


class createobject(forms.ModelForm):
    wid = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ))
    txt = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ))


    class Meta:
        model = models.tobjects
        fields = ['wid', 'objtypegisid', 'objgisid', 'condgenid', 'condriskid', 'condratsid', 'condmhcoverid', 'condmhwallid', 'condpipehydrsid', 'condpipehydreid', 'condpipedepvolsid', 'condpipedepvoleid', 'condpipedepconssid', 'condpipedepconseid', 'txt']
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^workorder/create/$', views.workorder_create, name='create_workorder'),
    url(r'^workorder/edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.workorder_edit, name='edit_workorder'),
    url(r'^workorder/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.workorder, name='workorder'),
    url(r'^home/$', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
    url(r'^workorders/$', views.workorders_list, name='workorders_list'),
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) on model formsets and how to limit the QuerySet? And note that `extra` is a parameter of `modelformset_factory`, not of the resulting Formset class.

Comment: I have gone through it maybe not as much as I should.

Comment: So yes, just add the queryset to filter your `tobjects` by `wid`.

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten I have added the queryset